# How do I get the following code to work on a Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

This code works on Chrome but does not work on Safari. The circle markers on the map are supposed to open up.

```css
html {
  background: #eaeaea;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.description {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.7);
}

div, img, footer {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36pt;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24pt;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18pt;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 14pt;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 12pt;
}

strong {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dff3fd;
}
a:visited {
  color: #dff3fd;
}
li.active a, a:hover, a:active {
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.centered-y {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.distribution-map > img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  background: #e69c53;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}
.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 220px;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover, .distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #afe1fa;
}
```

```html
   

 <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<h1>Qualität die weltweit hörbar ist</h1>
<p class="description">This doesn&rsquo;t look great at small sizes &mdash; in the original, I have an alternate rule for displaying on mobile devices. <strong>Click the points to expand them.</strong></p>
<div class="distribution-map">
    <!-- This was broken for a while because imgur :( -->
    <!-- I don't trust this host. Image here if it goes down: https://i.imgur.com/M7aUkuS.png -->
    <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/jnd9wc0n9/M7a_Uku_S.png">
    <!--In the original application, these points are injected with Javascript, but ideally, they'd be injected with a haml loop. Because I'm hardcoding content, I'm presenting this as prerendered HTML-->
    <button class="map-point" style="top:15%;left:35%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Nordamerika</h2>
                <p>You can put plenty of details in here. In the original, I listed contact information and linked phone numbers and email addresses.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:35%;left:50%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another Place</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum something something</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:76%;left:82.5%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Marauder Town</h2>
                <p>I solemnly swear that I am up to no good</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:45%;left:16%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Nordamerika</h2>
                <p>Englisch, Spanisch</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:60%;left:53%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Toto</h2>
                <p>I bless the rains</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:45%;left:75%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Asiatisch</h2>
                <p>Chinesische Sprecher</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
<p class="description">It&rsquo;s been brought to my attention that OSX/Safari doesn&rsquo;t support :active for buttons with default settings, so you guys will have to resort to JS or hold down your mouse button to keep :focus triggered.</p>
```

I was wondering how to fix the codes so that they will work properly? I'm not sure if it needs javascript to work or not. Here is the original code I got this from if it helps:
https://codepen.io/tosa/pen/XjEOzJ?q=interactive+map&limit=all&type=type-pens

Comment: Which part of "It’s been brought to my attention that OSX/Safari doesn’t support :active for buttons with default settings, so you guys will have to resort to JS or hold down your mouse button to keep :focus triggered." is unclear?

Comment: It was clear, just not sure how to add javascript to make it work.

Comment: Add a `click` event listener to the buttons that adds a class to the content inside it that you want to display, and removes the class from all the other content DIVs. Set the CSS for this class to do the transformation that makes it visible.

Comment: And optionally add a mouseout handler that removes this class again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `.map-point` elements from `button` to `a` and add a `tabindex` attribute to each one.

Demo at https://codepen.io/gpetrioli/full/dZrgoM/